# Fabric Integration with Debug build for iOS Application

Tags: ios, crashlytics, google-fabric

I'm trying to setup Fabric iOS for debug build but it is working fine on production as I downloaded dysm files from appstoreconnect and added to my fabric dashboard. Is there any way to integrate with debug or local builds for internal testing.

I have integrated Fabric using Pods. So initial setup and keys integration is done. I have tested the crashlytics with release builds for iOS, it works fine.

Comment: +1 It would be immensely useful to be able to enable crash reporting on debug build for iOS apps for debugging purpose.

Comment: Yes it is useful, do you have any solution to above question

Comment: No I don't have solution, but I am looking for one.

Comment: Thanks, what's the issue here? I suspect you could turn off Bitcode and not see this behavior.

Comment: @ToddBurner Bitcode is on but can't see the debugging on Crashlytics, maybe due to debug mode?